# laser_scan_matcher bulding package on Fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've successfully set up laser_scan_package on Electric. Now, I would like to build laser_scan_matcher package on Fuerte but I got the following error message:

```
 CSM previously patched, use make wipe to completely remove build directory.
 cd build/csm-git && mkdir -p deploy
 cd build/csm-git && cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/scan_tools/csm -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING="-fPIC"
-- Create a file named 'local_config/local-user-laptop.cmake' if you want to add options.
gsl home: 
DBG GSL_CONFIG GSL_CONFIG-NOTFOUND
FATAL_ERROR,FindGSL.cmake: gsl-config not found. Please set it manually.      
GSL_CONFIG=GSL_CONFIG-NOTFOUND
CMake Error at sm/CMakeLists.txt:30 (MESSAGE):
GSL not found.
```

How to solve the GSL problem. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45814/laser_scan_matcher-bulding-package-on-fuerte/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-01**:
@alfa_80
what is the command of installing  laser_scan_package on Fuerte ?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2013-02-01**:
Last time I used, I've just checkout via git from the repository on ros.org. But now, when I was trying to search the link for you, it returns an error of ""laser_scan_matcher" is either not a ROS package or not yet indexed."  I think, it's yet to be indexed..wait until next Monday perhaps :-)

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-01**:
OK..thanks :)

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2013-02-03**:
@marwa: here is the command: "git clone [https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools.git"](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools.git%22), the laser_scan_matcher should reside in the scan_tools directory. Hope that helps..

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-03**:
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you make sure you install all required dependencies first (e.g. via rosdep install)?

The quick fix would be to do `apt-get install gsl0-dev` and that would get you the required GSL dependency.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-10-15**:
Thanks a lot, that works :-)

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2013-05-27**:
just a small correction> sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev

**Comment by [kwiesz91](https://answers.ros.org/users/23432/kwiesz91/) on 2015-09-10**:
Thanks!  They must have their package set up slightly wrong or outdated because I ran rosdep install and it said that everything was there.